# Render not working on second method in controller

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, erb

I am implementing a phone and sim checker that consists of a user first inputting a phone number. If the phone number entered is in the database, this form disappears and a second form appears to check if the users sim number is in the database.
The problem I am currently having is the first method (def phonechecker) renders phone-found.js.erb, phone-not-found.js.erb and error.js.erb fine. But I am getting a template error:

```
Missing template phones/phone-not-found, application/phone-not-found with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :axlsx, :haml]}.
```

This error appears when I try to render the same template/s again after has sumbitted their sim_number, when running the simchecker method.

Code Below:

app/controllers/phones_controller.rb

```
class PhonesController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  def checkphone
    @phone_number = Phone.where('phone_number = ?', params[:phone][:phone_number])
    if @phone_number.exists?
      render 'phone-found'

    elsif @phone_number.blank?
      render 'phone-not-found'

    else
      render 'errors'
    end
  end

  def checksim
    @sim_number = Phone.where('sim_number = ?', params[:sim][:sim_number])
    if @sim_number.exists?
      render 'phone-found'

    elsif @sim_number.blank?
      render 'phone-not-found'

    else
      render 'errors'
    end
  end

  private

  def phone_params
    params.require(:phone).permit(
      :phone_number
    )
  end

  def sim_params
    params.require(:sim).permit(
      :sim_number
    )
  end
end
```

app/views/phones/phone-found.js.erb

```
$('#phone-number-found').append("<%= j render(partial: 'sim') %>")
$('#phone-number-not-found').html('');
$('#phone-number-error').html('');
$('#phone_phone_number').hide();
```

app/views/phones/phone-not-found.js.erb

```
$('#phone-number-found').html('');
$('#phone-number-not-found').html('Working!');
$('#phone-number-error').html('');
```

app/views/phones/error.js.erb

```
$('#phone-number-found').html('');
$('#phone-number-not-found').html('');
$('#phone-number-error').html('Working!');
```

app/views/phones/_sim.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :sim, :url => url_for(:action => 'checksim', :controller => 'phones'), remote: true, :authenticity_token => false, html: { id: 'sim-number-form'}  do |f| %>
  <div id="phone-number-found"></div>
  <div id="phone-number-not-found"></div>
  <div id="phone-number-error"></div>
  <%= f.text_field :sim_number %>
  <%= submit_tag("Check") %>
<% end %>
```

app/views/phones/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :phone, :url => url_for(:action => 'checkphone', :controller => 'phones'), remote: true, :authenticity_token => false, html: { id: 'phone-number-form'}  do |f| %>
  <div id="phone-number-found"></div>
  <div id="phone-number-not-found"></div>
  <div id="phone-number-error"></div>
  <%= f.text_field :phone_number %>
  <%= submit_tag("Check") %>
<% end %>
```

config/routes.rb

```
post "/checkphone" => "phones#checkphone"
  post "/checksim" => "phones#checksim"

  resources :phones, path: '4g-promo'
```

Would be greatly appreciated if someone could solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: template not found usually happens because template not found: try => render template: "phones/phone-not-found", or replace '-' with '_' in the name of your file, or make it a partial starting with : '_your_file.erb'

Comment: Just an aside, not directly relating to your problem: You should be using `Phone.where(phone_number: x)` instead of `.where('phone_number = ?', x)`. Same with your `sim_number` column. If you want a `where` condition with straight equality, just give ActiveRecord a hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the error you can see that it's looking for html `:formats=>[:html]` or one of those variants: `:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :axlsx, :haml`. But you want it to look for a `.js.erb`. You need to add a respond_to method within the controller method like:

```
def checksim
  @sim_number = Phone.where('sim_number = ?', params[:sim][:sim_number])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @sim_number.exists?
      format.js {render 'phone-found'}
    elsif @sim_number.blank?
      format.js {render 'phone-not-found'}
    else
      format.js {render 'errors'}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! That didnt work unfortunately, dont know if im doing it right but this is what i put in my method and tried:
`ef checksim
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {}
    end
    @sim_number = Phone.where('sim_number = ?', params[:sim][:sim_number])
    if @sim_number.exists?
      render 'phone-found'

    elsif @sim_number.blank?
      render 'phone-not-found'

    else
      render 'errors'
    end
  end`

The error I got was ActionController::UnkownFormat

Comment: I updated the example to show how you would have to do it

Comment: Also here is link to rails documentation section that shows example http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#server-side-concerns

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately getting the same error:
ActionController::UnkownFormat on respond_to do |format| :/

Comment: Maybe make sure `remote: true` is working right on your form? Can you verify that on submit the form is making an AJAX request?

Comment: And last ditch effort, I read a couple of people mentioning that adding a `format.html` right under each `format.js` can work when getting that error even though that seems buggy/weird. Worth a shot https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2014/10/07/rails-respond_to-return-unknown-format-error/

Comment: Ah I saw this, thankyou. Will try this tomorrow when I'm back at work

Comment: Managed to fix this. I was appending the _sim partial (sim number form) to a div that was within my phone number form, which was causing the error. Schoolboy error. Thanks for your help. Will approve your answer :)